# MFP Server: Specifying a particular interface on a multi-homed host

Tags: mobilefirst-server

MFP 7.0.0 with IF201506081356 
on WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.5 on Linux

My idea was to modify server.xml

```
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" 
          host="*" >  <=== change this to a specific ipaddress
```

And change this JNDI entry

```
  <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.host" value="localhost"/>
```

to specify the same ipaddress.

After making those changes server does not initialise correctly, it attempts to access JMX on the localhost, even though nowhere in my serverl.xml is the word "localhost"

```
[6/11/15 13:19:24:232 CEST] 00000040 com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     I Establishing REST connection to service:
 jmx:rest://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST SSL handler=null
```

That attempt just repeats ad nauseum ...

Is there some cached value somewhere? Something else I need to set?

Comment: Could you work around this temporarily with firewall configuration? i.e. block the server from connecting out/in on the other interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the startup of the runtimes "localhost" is always used for the JMX connection. It is a defect, an APAR will be created.

Comment: But it surely must use the jmx "port" parameter as we can run several servers on the same machine? But it ignores jmx host specification? Can you see any way to restrict the server to a chosen interface? This behaviour seems to prevent it.

Comment: Yes it should take the value of the ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.host property but it is not unfortunately the case. So as I said it is not normal and I've created an APAR to fix this.

Comment: Bruno, could you edit in the APAR number for future ref please?

Comment: The APAR number is PI42851